# Check my proof on showing $|H|=|\mathcal{H}||K|$, where $|H|$ and $|\mathcal{H}|$ are corresponding subgroup in the correspondence theorem?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

Let $\phi:G\to\mathcal{G}$ be a surjective homomorphism with kernel $K$. There is a bijective correspondence between subgroups of $\mathcal{G}$ (where we denote as $\mathcal{H}=\phi(H)$) and subgroups of $G$  that contain $K$ (where we denote as $H$).

I am trying to show that if $H$ and $\mathcal{H}$ are corresponding subgroups, then $|H|=|\mathcal{H}||K|$.

I tried using the counting formula, we have $|G|=|\text{ker }\phi|\cdot|\text{im }\phi|$. We can then restrict the map $\phi$ to $H$, and we get $\phi|_H:H\to\mathcal{G}$. And by definition, we get $\text{ker }(\phi|_H)=(\text{ker }\phi)\cap H$. So we have, $|H|=|\text{ker }\phi\cap H|\cdot|\phi(H)|=|K\cap H|\cdot|\mathcal{H}|$.

This is where I got stuck, unless $|K\cap H|=|K|$, but I don't think we can show that.

Is there any mistake in my proof? Could somebody give me some hints on how to fix my proof?

Thanks!

Comment: Wait, *you* said that $H$ contains $K$, right? So what is $K \cap H$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact what you are trying to prove is a direct consequence of the first isomorphism thm. You can prove it by taking $g: G/K \rightarrow$ image$(\phi)$: $g(x + K) = \phi(x)$

Comment: I see. Can we prove without using the first isomorphism theorem instead?

Comment: Don't see how but it should be possible

Comment: @user338393 See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The correspondence theorem is talking about subgroups $H \subseteq G$ with $\ker \phi \subseteq H$. $$\therefore, \ker \phi \cap H = \ker \phi \implies |\ker \phi \cap H| = |\ker \phi|$$